# C# Dynamically calling on a function within a loop

Tags: c#, xml

I have an XML file I am trying to change. All the values within the XML file have a value from a separate class I need to push onto it.

Here is a loop will successfully change everything within my XML file to say "Hello".

```
            foreach (System.Xml.XmlNode childNode in aNode.ChildNodes)
            {
                string attributename = childNode.Attributes["name"].Value;
                childNode.FirstChild.InnerText = "Hello";
            }
```

The values that must be put onto the XML file will come from calling the separate class and using the attributename.

The attributename will be, SQLUsername, SQLPassword... etc.

The parameters pulled from the separate class are pulled using

```
        CDSPassword.Default.SQLUsername;

        CDSPassword.Default.SQLPassword;
```

So I need to push the attributename to the XXX in CDSPassword.Default.XXX, each time I go through the loop. Such as

```
            foreach (System.Xml.XmlNode childNode in aNode.ChildNodes)
            {
                string attributename = childNode.Attributes["name"].Value;
                childNode.FirstChild.InnerText = CDSPassword.Default.attributename;
            }
```

The issue becomes there is no "attributename" within CDSPassword.Default, but the string value of attributename will be the SQLUser, password, etc.

Comment: you can use *Reflection* to get value  from ``CDSPassword.Default`` in the Runtime. can you share the `Default` class and xml content will help for test?

Comment: Yes this seems to work. Although there is one entry within my CDSPassword.Default that returns a null?  What could cause this?